VSCode trying to autocomplete entire lines
I'm trying to learn JavaScript and it's annoying me that VSCode keeps trying to autocomplete entire lines based off of what it "thinks" I'm trying to type. It's really annoying because when I'm trying to type GetElementById then it autofills with what it thinks I'm trying to type, and I can't just hit tab to autocomplete the GetElementById because it tries to fill in the entire LINE!
Is there a keybind or something to JUST autocomplete the part that it shows below? And not all of what it thinks I'm trying to type? For me, the best way to learn is by typing it out piece by piece and not autocompleting ENTIRE lines. (using the suggestive type is fine for me though), even if it's repetitive. I JUST want it to autocomplete the GetElementById, I don't want it to autocomplete whatever the hell it thinks I'm going to type. Does anyone know what to change to get it to stop?

I disabled every extension that claims that it has "AI" and disabled every extension except "HTML 5 Boilerplate" "HTML CSS Support" and "HTML Preview" (Last one just lets you see the webpage in VSCode) and it still is trying to autocomplete entire lines. I just want it to autocomplete what it says below the line like "GetElementById" "GetElementByClassName" "GetElementByName" "GetElementByTagName" and such. I don't want it to try to autocomplete everything that it thinks I'm going to type.

That really looks like a copilot-style thing, though I'm not an expert on VSCode. If you reload VSCode after disabling the AI extensions does it change anything? Can you post the results of code --list-extensions --show-versions?

Yes I can in a bit. I just left to help my friend out with something. I didn't think about themes. I'll do this and send the results when I get home. Thanks!
